# How to store currently logged on user in DB?

Tags: java, jsf, jpa, seam

Using Seam 2.1.2 and JSF 1.2 I wonder how to store the users login name in the database.

In plain JSF I would simply lookup `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser();`in a backing bean and set the value into a persistent object.

How can I achieve that the users name will be stored in the DB?

Comment: That's a pretty broad question. At which step exactly are you stucking? Creating the DB table? Is your actual problem in the DB, JSF or JPA?

Comment: @BalusC, due to the lack of a layer (except Seam) between JSF and EJB I can't figure out where to do the lookup in FacesContext, JPA,JSF already works but where to put glue code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject a Credentials component

```
private @In Credentials credentials;
```

So retrieve your logged user by using

```
credentials.getUsername();
```